# Differential equations regarding the population at a given time t

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

This is a question I came across while taking a detour through questions of differential equations:-

$Q.$ The population as a function of time $t$ and age $A$ follows these rules...

$1.$ Number of people with age $A \in (a,a+\Delta a)$ at a given time $t$ is $f(t,a)\Delta a$.

$2.$ Each year, the probability of dying at age $A\in(a,a+\Delta a)=r_D(t,a)\Delta a$.

$3.$ Each year, the probability of giving birth to a baby at age $A \in (a,a+\Delta a)=r_B(t,a)\Delta a$

Part ($i$): Given the above rules, make an equation accounting for the number of people at time $t+\Delta t$ and age $A=a$, given the population at time $t$.

Part ($ii$): Take limit $\Delta t \to 0$ and $\Delta A \to 0$ and derive a partial differential equation governing the population dynamics as a function of time and age.

Part ($iii$): Given the $3rd$ rule, make an accounting of the number of people with age $A=0$.

Part ($iv$): Take limit $\Delta a \to 0$ and derive an integral condition for the number of people starting out at an age $a=0$.

I don't have much experience with DEs as such, so i am gonna need some help here. More importantly, i really don't have any idea about how to do the first part at all.

Comment: "the probability of giving birth to a baby at age $A \in (a,a+\Delta a)=r_B(t,a)\Delta a$" sounds interesting : ). It's ok though since $r_B$ is not given yet...

Comment: @velutluna , realistically speaking $r_B$ is either $0$ or very close to $0$ for like $60{%}$ of all the permissible $a$'s. Btw an answer would be more preferable.